# What is a day in the week called?

Tags: word-request

A weekday is a day of the week other than Saturday or Sunday.

What is a day in the week called?

Comment: Just "a day", probably. Because each day belongs to some week, there may be no need for a special term

Comment: I guess you could say "day of the weekend". but people usually say "on/during the weekend". As in "Do you want to get dinner on a weekday or on the weekend?"

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know whether something occurs on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc., the unambiguous expression is *day **of** the week*, as used for example in *[All in a day’s work: the days of the week](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/07/days-of-the-week/)* at the OxfordWords blog, or in the Wikipedia article *[Names of the days of the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_days_of_the_week)*. The answer to *what day of the week is the 20th?* is *Friday* in November 2015. The answer to *what day of the week was 15 June 1215* is *Monday*.

The day of any other period will be given as its number within the period. At this writing, therefore, the answer to *What day of the month is this Friday?* is *the 20th*, and to *What day of the month is Thanksgiving in the U.S.?* is *the 26th*. But this is a far [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20day%20of%20the%20week%2Cwhat%20day%20of%20the%20month%2Cwhat%20day%20of%20the%20year&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) request. It is conventional to use the *date* (day, month, and year together, or at least month and day) rather than the day of the quarter, day of the year, etc. except in specialized uses in certain fields. And for specialized uses, the type of day is nearly always specified— the sidereal day, the Julian day, and so on.

As such, someone asking *[what day is it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81357)?* will likely be asking what day of the week it is, unless they are asking seeking recognition rhetorically for some special occasion like a [birthday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATyHIT5LV8g) or [Christmas](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/schoolradio/subjects/english/a_christmas_carol/audio_clips/episode_9).